# How to export logs for certain interval from Kibana Observability/Logs/Stream?

Tags: logging, export, kibana, observability

We need to export logs from the stream for a specific time interval (which is set on the top of the main stream frame) into JSON, CSV or any other human-readable format.
The logs "live" 7 days in our system and we often need to have logs to hand after this period of time for developers (like a black box). Is there a possibility to grab them somehow?

Any help is highly appreciated in advance!